# Photoshop, arrange layers to minimize total surface without overlap

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I print sheets with many separate objects loaded as layers from Photoshop. Is there a way to automatically arrange them on the sheet so that they do not overlap and that they take the least space possible?

If this is not possible from within Photoshop, is there some other way to do this?

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate more? like which kind of object u placing on sheet? demo image will help us understand more :)

Comment: @DesignPhoenix I added the example...

Answer (score 3):

What you probably need is a texture packer, for instance there's a simple free [Atlas Maker](https://github.com/richardjdare/Atlasmaker) script for Photoshop. In the Destination Image tab change document size to whatever printing size you need and then browse for your images. Packing methods aren't ideal but still do the job done.

[image]

Input folder:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems like something that could be of use to me. I will check it out and report the results! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the rotation function is not yet implemented, so I can't really use the tool. Such a shame...

Comment: if you mean rotation like in your example (non-90°), I don't think there's a tool like this for Photoshop (because it's a destructive transformation)